# Is there a .NET version of Concordion?

Tags: .net, automated-tests, concordion, nbehave

Apart from [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/) is there anything like concordion for .NET?

> [Concordion](http://www.concordion.org/) is an open source framework
>   for Java that lets you turn a plain
>   English description of a requirement
>   into an automated test

David Peterson (the author of Concordion) has told me that there is no .net port of Concordion that he knows of.  However he says I should look at [Nbehave](http://www.codeplex.com/NBehave) (and [here](http://code.google.com/p/nbehave/)) as well as FitNesse.

I have also found [Twist](http://studios.thoughtworks.com/twist-agile-test-automation/) that [Thoughtworks Studios](http://studios.thoughtworks.com) has just released, it is not cheep.  It claims to support Selenium and Frankenstein out of the box, on a quick look, its Domain Specific Languages look a lot like Concordion.  **However it is Java, not .NET**  Thoughtworks claims..

> Twist is the next generation of
>   software test automation tools. It
>   provides a rich environment for
>   authoring, executing, and maintaining
>   tests.

Comment: Ian, Concordion.NET is moving along nicely if you want to check it out: http://code.google.com/p/concordion-net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[concordion-net](http://code.google.com/p/concordion-net/) is a .net port of Concordion, apparently "its still pretty alpha".

Also consider [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/).

Comment: It is pretty alpha, but I'm looking for contributors!

Comment: I now have a series of blog posts describing how to use it @ http://living-in-concordion.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

[StoryTeller](http://storyteller.tigris.org/) does what you want.  It actually goes a step farther than Concordion, providing a UI that allows the creation of tests without knowing HTML or the structure of the test fixtures.  This allows folks like BAs, TPMs, and QAs to write and execute tests easily.

Answer (score 1):

A new version of Concordion.NET has been release. Please find some documentation here:
http://concordion.org/dotnet/

Now Concordion.NET has a NUnit integration to run the Concordion.NET tests:
https://github.com/concordion/concordion-net/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Cheers,
Jacek